# Link in Angular component is not working looks impossible to click

Tags: angular, html, typescript, angular6

When we try to click to navigate user's profile nothing happens also it looks impossible to click anyway. Here is the code:

**TypeScript**

```
  ViewUser(user) {
    this.router.navigate([user.username]);
    if (this.loggedInUser.username !== user.username) {
      this.userService.ProfileNotifications(user._id).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.socket.emit('refresh', {});
        },
        err => console.log(err)
      );
    }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="card card-person">
    <a (click)="ViewUser(user)">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/cloud_name/image/upload/v{{user.picVersion}}/{{user.picId}}"
       alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title"> {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</h4>
        <p class="card-text">{{user.age}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">{{user.country}},{{user.city}}</p>
        <p class="material-icons" *ngIf="CheckIfOnline(user.username)">online</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn button-image closeButton btn-message" [routerLink]="['/chat', user.username]">Message</a>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

By clicking it should navigate to the user profile page. Also, it doesn't show any error in the console since as I said it's impossible even to click. What is wrong?

Comment: a link (a) containing a div containing an other link ? not good

Comment: remove the `href`

Comment: Probably CSS is causing error, check `z-index` carefully.

Comment: There is no z-index at all and not added any style for a tag.

Comment: post your route config here, maybe there is something wrong with your routing setup

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is an angular error. I think it is related to the styling of the `<a>` tag it is inline by default.
you can add to your-component.css these lines

```
a.fill {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
}
```

or if you use bootstrap you can add the `nav-link` class to your tag like

```
<a class="nav-link" (click)="ViewUser(user)">
```